# SSIS fuzzy lookup issue

Tags: ssis, fuzzy-search

I have an issue with SSIS and Fuzzy Lookup.

If I set the minnimum similarity to 0,7 and search for:

Brian Ølet

I would expect that the name:

Brian Ölet

Would show in the result set. But for some reason these special letters are giving SSIS and the fuzzy lookup function a hard time.

Is there a way around that issue?

Any help is highly appriciated!

Comment: What is the database you are connecting to?  Is the datatype a varchar or nvarchar (nvarchar for MSSQL lets you have special characters, basic varchar does not for all special characters)

Comment: It's an SQL server 2016 and the lookup field is of the type varchar. But i can find both types of characters in the coloumn. So I still don't get, but I can try and change it to nvarchar if that will solve the problem.